# Independence using Conditional Distributions

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

If $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are mutually independent, I'd like to show
$$
P(X_1 < X_3, X_2 < X_3 \mid X_3) = P(X_1 < X_3 \mid X_3)\cdot P(X_2 < X_3 \mid X_3), \quad a.s.
$$
Here's what I have:

The conditional probabilities are functions on the sample space $\Omega$ that are defined to satisfy, for any $C \in \sigma(X_3)$,
\begin{align*}
\int_C P(X_1 < X_3 \mid X_3)\, dP & = P(X_1 < X_3, C) \\
\int_C P(X_2 <X_3 \mid X_3)\, dP & = P(X_2 < X_3, C) \\
\int_C P(X_1 < X_3, X_2 <X_3 \mid X_3)\, dP & = P(X_1 < X_3, X_2 < X_3, C)
\end{align*}

I can't seem to get anywhere from here, though, as it's not clear how the original independence can be used.

Comment: $C$ should be in $\sigma(X_3)$.

Comment: And indicating that this question is [a follow-up of another recent one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1962704/6179) was not an option because?

Comment: Re the mathematical question itself, if you had asked it on the other page, I would probably have indicated that proving the defining property for $C=[X_3\in B]$ was enough for the general case, and that for such events $C$, the result was more or less direct... but now I am not sure I should indicate this. :-)

Comment: @Jack changed, thanks.

Comment: @Did I'm not quite following...the event $C$ is exactly of the form you wrote.  Could you explain how writing it as $X_3 \in B$ is useful?

Comment: Wrong page, cannot answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F_i$, for $i=1, \ldots, 3$, be the respective distribution function of $X_i$. Then, for any Borel set $B$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{X_3 \in B} P(X_1 < X_3\mid X_3) dP &=\int_{\Omega}1_{X_1<X_3} 1_{X_3 \in B} dP \\
&=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} 1_{x< z} 1_{z\in B} dF_1(x) dF_3(z)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} F_1(z) 1_{z\in B} dF_3(z)\\
&=\int_{\Omega} F_1(X_3)1_{X_3 \in B} dP \\
&=\int_{X_3 \in B}F_1(X_3) dP.
\end{align*}
That is, $$E(X_1 < X_3 \mid X_3) = F_1(X_3).$$
Similarly, $$E(X_2 < X_3 \mid X_3) = F_2(X_3).$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_{X_3 \in B} 1_{X_1 < X_3} 1_{X_2 < X_3} dP &= \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}1_{x<z}1_{y<z}1_{z\in B} dF_1(x)dF_2(y)dF_3(z)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} F_1(z)F_2(z) 1_{z\in B} dF_3(z)\\
&=\int_{\Omega}F_1(X_3) F_2(X_3) 1_{X_3 \in B} dP \\
&=\int_{X_3 \in B}F_1(X_3) F_2(X_3) dP\\
&=\int_{X_3 \in B} E(X_1 < X_3 \mid X_3) E(X_2 < X_3 \mid X_3) dP.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$E(X_1 < X_3, X_2 < X_3 \mid X_3) = E(X_1 < X_3 \mid X_3) E(X_2 < X_3 \mid X_3). $$